# jQuery don't run on my local server

Tags: jquery

I have wrote this code on my local server (Installed Apache 2 on my Mac with MacPorts) but It haven't run.

JavasSript is active on Safari or Firefox, but it haven't do on these.
Is this code worse? Or I can try other way? Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> jquery test </title>
   <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script>
     // Load jQuery
     google.load("jquery", "1");
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    JQuery(function($){
     var $curr = $(".sel");
     $("button").click(function(){
      $curr.removeClass("sel");
      $curr.$curr.prev().addClass("sel") 
     });
    });
   </script>
   <style type="text/css">
   span { padding :8px;}
   .sel { border :orange solid 4px;}
   </style>
      </head>
      <body> 
   <p>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span class="sel">3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <button>click</button>
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `jQuery` instead of `JQuery`, you'll get a JavaScript error calling a variable that doesn't exist :)

Also this has an extra `$curr`:

```
$curr.$curr.prev().addClass("sel")
```

It should just be:

```
$curr.prev().addClass("sel")
```

[You can see a version with both of these fixes here](http://jsfiddle.net/rCuEJ/)

---

If you always want to move back one, you need to move your selector inside the click, instead of always referring to the original element that had `class="sel"`, like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".sel").removeClass("sel").prev().addClass("sel");
  });
});​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/rCuEJ/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It works! I mistook "jQuery" spell.
And jsfiddle is cool.

Answer (score 0):

To help you debug, both safari and firefox has javascript error/output logs. On firefox press control shift j to open up the console, here you can see what went wrong.

Comment: thank you for your help. I want also cool debuging way with js, but I didn't it. awasome!